# Как сделать поиск по всем значениям?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Как реализовать поиск по всем значениям на Angular2. Вот код:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(projects: any, search: any): any {
  if(search === undefined) return projects;

    return projects.filter(function(project)
    {
    return project.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    })

  }

}
```

На данный момент он может искать только по имени, а как сделать так чтобы он мог искать по всем значениям которые есть в таблице (например по иду, имени, фамилии, стране и т.д.)

Comment: Впилить datatables :) https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome